# Place tab in Shiny tabsetPanel on the right

Tags: css, r, shiny, bootstrap-4

By default tabs in a `tabsetPanel` are put on the left. Is it possible to place a tab on the right side, while still having other tabs on the left? So that it looks like this?

[image]

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("tab_left1"),
    tabPanel("tab_left2"),
    tabPanel("tab_right")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `float-right` should indeed work. The problem with using 2 `tabsetPanel` is that there are 2 active tabs at the same time.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      ".tabbable ul li:nth-child(3) { float: right; }"
    ))
  ),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("tab_left1"),
    tabPanel("tab_left2"),
    tabPanel("tab_right")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can create 2 `tabsetPanel` and pull one over to the right?

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  div(style="display:inline-block",tabsetPanel(type = c("pills"),tabPanel("tab_left1"),tabPanel("tab_left2"))),
  div(style="display:inline-block;float: right",tabsetPanel(type = c("pills"),tabPanel("tab_right")))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you apply the class `float-right` to the ones you want to float to the right, it should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I added   `tags$style(HTML("
    .tabbable > .nav > li > a[data-value='tab_right'] {float:right}
    "))` to the UI, but it does not work. What's wrong?