# Some right-aligned tabPanels in shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

Using `navbarPage` I would like to have some `tabPanels` to be right-aligned while the rest of `tabPanels` and `navbarMenus` to be left-aligned:

So, instead of this

```
library(shiny)    
ui =  tagList(
  navbarPage(
    title = "My app",
    navbarMenu("Left1",
               tabPanel("Subleft11"),
               tabPanel("Subleft12")),
    tabPanel("Left2"),
    tabPanel("Left3"),
    tabPanel("Right1"),
    tabPanel("Right2")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

I would like to get something like this:

[image]

Solution from [GyD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223155/place-tab-in-shiny-tabsetpanel-on-the-right) works fine for `tabsetPanel` but I was not able to adapt it to `navbarPage`. I tried to add

```
tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      ".navbar ul li:nth-child(4) { float: right; }
      .navbar ul li:nth-child(5) { float: right; }"
    ))),
```

but without desired effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do that with some css.
This would be an easy example which aligns the 4th and 5th list elements inside the class `navbar-nav` a `float: right;`.

By including `right: 150px;` to the 4th child, you keep the tabs in correct order.

App.R

```
library(shiny)   
library(shinythemes)  

ui =  tagList(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
                           .navbar-nav {
                           float: none !important;
                           }
                           .navbar-nav > li:nth-child(4) {
                           float: right;
                           right: 150px;
                           }
                           .navbar-nav > li:nth-child(5) {
                           float: right;
                           }
                           "))),
  navbarPage(
    title = "My app",
    theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
    navbarMenu("Left1",
               tabPanel("Subleft11"),
               tabPanel("Subleft12")),
    tabPanel("Left2"),
    tabPanel("Left3"),

    tabPanel("Right1"),
    tabPanel("Right2")

    )
    )

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, there are some blank tabs next to the title. Moreover, `tabPanels` on the right side are in reverse order.

Comment: My bad, the 2 ghost tabs appeared because I placed the style inside the navbarPage. I edited my answer, but they are still showing in reverse order.

Comment: A hacky solution, but you could give the first right tabpPanel a css `right: 150px;`. this way they will appear correctly. I thought of putting both in a div and let that div float right, but the tabs didnt show up at all then. Answer is edited.

Comment: I noticed that this does not work when using some `shinytheme`, e.g. `theme = shinytheme("cerulean")`. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: It apparently overwrites the `.navbar-nav` to `float: left`. If you include `!important` it is correct again. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something along these lines:

```
tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
    "
    .navbar-header { width: 10% }
    .navbar-nav { width: 90% }
    .navbar-nav>li:nth-child(4) { float: right; }
    .navbar-nav>li:nth-child(5) { float: right; }"
)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This works nice but tabs are in reverse order as in solution by @SeGa. Moreover, for wide screen, there will be quite a gap between first tab and title.