# Aligning tabPanel to right in shiny app using css

Tags: css, r, shiny

#### Summary:

I am trying to replicate tabBox from shinydashboard but without loading shinydashboard. I have done this using tabsetPanel and tabPanel. I want to float 3rd tab to the right (for titles) every time I set one of the tabsetPanel, however there are occasions where I don't want this to happen. I feel I might need to introduce some sort of custom ID or class in CSS so that I have control which tabsets should all float left.

#### What I have tried so far:

I have used the following solutions:

1. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48227573/4621702) floats right 3rd tabs found in ALL tabsets in the dashboard. It will be good if I can specify
2. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48226790/4621702) is promising however the tab space is now split because of the 2 tabsetPanels.

```
library(shiny)

ui <-  fluidPage(

  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      ".nav-tabs li:nth-child(3) { float: right; pointer-events: none; cursor: default;}"

    ))),

        navbarPage(title = NULL

          ,tabPanel(title = "Nav tab 1"
              ,tabsetPanel(type = "tabs"
                           ,tabPanel(title = "Tab 1"
                                     ,column(
                                       width = 6
                                       ,tabsetPanel(type = "tabs"
                                          ,tabPanel(title = "Chart")
                                          ,tabPanel(title = "Table")
                                          ,tabPanel(title = "Box Title 1 #correct")
                                       )
                                     )
                                     ,column(
                                       width = 6
                                       ,tabsetPanel(type = "tabs"
                                                    ,tabPanel(title = "Chart")
                                                    ,tabPanel(title = "Table")
                                                    ,tabPanel(title = "Box Title 2 #correct")
                                       )
                                     )
                            )

                           ,tabPanel(title = "Tab 2")
                           ,tabPanel(title = "Tab 3 #I don't want this to align right")
                           ,tabPanel(title = "Tab 4")
              )
         )
         ,tabPanel(title = "Nav tab 2")
         ,tabPanel(title = "Nav tab 3 - #not affected coz different class")
        )
      )

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The code I have included here incorporates solution #1 from the link above. As you can see by using css ".nav-tabs li:nth-child(3)" this is applied globally. Is there a way I can keep this CSS but use class or ID or *data-value = "Nav tab 1"* so I can apply float left css selectively? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @thothal I was able to introduce id's to particular tabsetpanel that I wanted its tabs to float right. Full solution below. Where I wanted the 3rd tab to float right, I added the id = "chart_tabs" and used the relevant css in header.

```
ui <-  fluidPage(

  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      "#chart_tabs li:nth-child(3) { float: right; pointer-events: none; cursor: default;}

      "

    ))),

  navbarPage(title = NULL

    ,tabPanel(title = "Nav tab 1"
       ,tabsetPanel(type = "tabs"
          ,tabPanel(title = "Tab 1"
            ,column(
              width = 6
              ,tabsetPanel(type = "tabs"
                ,id = "chart_tabs"
                ,tabPanel(title = "Chart")
                ,tabPanel(title = "Table")
                ,tabPanel(title = "Box Title 1 #correct")
              )
            )
            ,column(
              width = 6
              ,tabsetPanel(type = "tabs"
                ,id = "chart_tabs"
                ,tabPanel(title = "Chart")
                ,tabPanel(title = "Table")
                ,tabPanel(title = "Box Title 2 #correct")
              )
            )
          )

          ,tabPanel(title = "Tab 2")
          ,tabPanel(title = "Tab 3 #I don't want this to align right")
          ,tabPanel(title = "Tab 4")
       )
    )
    ,tabPanel(title = "Nav tab 2")
    ,tabPanel(title = "Nav tab 3 - #not affected coz different class")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to dynamically add/remove a class to your tabset element and adapt your css. You need to add an `id` to your tabset to be able to address it via javascript. You have to execute some javascript code, the easiest is by means of `library(shinyjs)`.

In the following example I toggle the class on an `actionButton` click, but you can adapt that according to your needs.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

style <- ".float-right li:nth-child(2) { float: right;}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(style))),
  navbarPage(title = "Move Me",
             tabPanel("Nav Tab 1",
                      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", id = "moveme",
                                  tabPanel(title = "Tab 1", 
                                           actionButton("move", "Move Tab2")),
                                  tabPanel(title = "Tab 2")
                      )
             ),
             tabPanel("Nav Tab 2")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$move, {
    toggleCssClass("moveme", "float-right")
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you @thothal, your suggestion of introducing id worked. I was looking for exactly this solution. I didn't use shinyjs though. I have added a working solution to my question, in case anyone is interested.